# Adding labels to google scatter charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization, scatter-plot

I am using google charts API to draw scatter, is there a way to label each node in the scatter diagram. I guess it only uses the numeric values.....Any other tools I can use instead.
Example:

```
Name  Age  Response 
Allen 12    40
Tom   16    45
Sim   17    60
```

X and y axis will be age and response respectively, but each node on the graph can I label as Allen, Tom, Sim

Answer (score 5):

You can label the points in a Google ScatterChart by adding a tooltip.  Tooltips show up when you mouseover a data point.

The code for your data table should look something like this:

```
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(
{
    cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'Age', type: 'number'},
           {id: 'B', label: 'Response', type: 'number'},
           {id: 'C', label: 'Name', type:'tooltip', p:{role:'tooltip'}}
          ],
    rows: [{c:[{v: 12}, {v: 40}, {v:'Allen'}]},
           {c:[{v: 16}, {v: 45}, {v:'Tom'}]},
           {c:[{v: 17}, {v: 60}, {v:'Sim'}]}
          ]
 },
 0.6
)
```

When you mouseover the points, the name will show up.

Link to Tooltips:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole

Link to DataTable class (for formatting data): 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable

NOTE: if you're trying to plot multiple data series, you have to specify a tooltip for each one.  For example, if you add a separate data series for Average Response, the code would change to:

```
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(
{
    cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'Age', type: 'number'},
           {id: 'B', label: 'Response', type: 'number'},
           {id: 'C', label: 'Name', type:'tooltip', p:{role:'tooltip'}},
           {id: 'D', label: 'AvgResp', type: 'number'},
           {id: 'E', label: 'Category', type:'tooltip', p:{role:'tooltip'}}
          ],
    rows: [{c:[{v: 12}, {v: 40}, {v:'Allen'}, {v:null}, {v:null}]},
           {c:[{v: 16}, {v: 45}, {v:'Tom'}, {v:null}, {v:null}]},
           {c:[{v: 17}, {v: 60}, {v:'Sim'}, {v:null}, {v:null}]},
           {c:[{v: 12}, {v: null}, {v:null}, {v: 35}, {v:'Avg. 12yo'}]},
           {c:[{v: 16}, {v: null}, {v:null}, {v: 48}, {v:'Avg. 16yo'}]},
           {c:[{v: 17}, {v: null}, {v:null}, {v: 52}, {v:'Avg. 17yo'}]}
          ]
 },
 0.6
)
```

Comment: How to plot those labels on chart?

Answer (score 4):

I was having same issue to plot labels for points on chart itself.
Google chart have solved this problem now. You can add one more property as `annotation`. By which you can add labels.

See how it looks like. Generally I do annotation in number and then explain what those number are about.

[image]

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Age', 'Weight', {role: 'annotation'}],
      [ 8,      12, 'Point 1'],
      [ 1,      5.5, 'Point 2'],
      [ 11,     14, 'Point 3'],
      [ 4,      5, 'Point 4'],
      [ 3,      3.5, 'Point 5'],
      [ 6.5,    7, 'Point 6']
    ]);
```

Comment: Alternative: if you use new DataTable, add column like this: data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}). See [doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) for detais.

Comment: @heringer: You should add new answer or update existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

To do it using the visualization API, just use a cell_object (https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#cell_object). The google API playground was useful for me, might be for you: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground

Here's an example of some code:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Age','Response'],
      [ {v:12, f: 'Allen'}, 40],
      [ {v:16, f: 'Tom'}, 45],
      [ {v:17, f: 'Sim'}, 60]
    ]);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: How to plot those labels on chart?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/scatter_charts#chart_types

This page documents coloring the plots and adding a legend.

With Google charts you can't, short of using the legend and cross referencing. I don't know of any scatter chart creator that will label the individual plots.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/scatter_charts to add labels of points ?

Comment: @SirOsis I have added solution for showing labels on chart